# Add author meta to a column in a wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a column to a custom post type called "Projects" that displays the authors location (city).

[image]

I got the column title to show up, but can't seem to render the data in the column itself.

It's displayed elsewhere on the site with:

```
<?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'city', $author_id ); ?>
```

SOLVED - HERE IS THE SOLUTION

```
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin_init' );
function my_admin_init() {
    add_filter( 'manage_edit-project_columns', 'test_modify_post_table' );
    add_action( 'manage_project_posts_custom_column', 'test_modify_post_table_row', 10, 2 );
}

function test_modify_post_table( $column ) {
    $column['city']  = 'Location';
    return $column;
}

function test_modify_post_table_row( $column_name, $post_id ) {

    $custom_fields = get_userdata($user_id);

    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'city' :
            echo get_the_author_meta( 'city', $author_id );
            break;

        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: This links must solve your problem. [One](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253640/adding-custom-columns-to-custom-post-types) , [Two](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen--wp-24934)

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks